# Событие при выделении jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ли свойство в jQuery, которое срабатывает при выделении текста? К примеру:

```
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Если мы выделяем "test" в `div`'e, то срабатывает определенная функция. `alert(1)` например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getSelectedText = function() {
    var text = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

$('#test').on('mouseup', function(){ 
    var text = getSelectedText();
    if (text != '') alert(text); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Такого события нету, но можно обрабатывать mouseup и keyup соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

ну или навесить события на keydown на пример на клавишы ctrl+c