# Как выделенный текст обернуть в тэг?

Tags: jquery

Есть простой текст в div-блоке. Как при выделении фрагмента этого текста обернуть его в тэг ? Или как сделать то же самое, но при клике на кнопку, как в визуальном редакторе?

Comment: Тут решение посмотри: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435967/Событие-при-выделении-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("mouseup", ".test", function() {
  styliString();
});

function styliString() {
  if (window.getSelection() == '') {
    return false;
  }
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.appendChild(selectionContents);
  span.setAttribute("class", "selected");
  span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  span.style.color = "green";
  range.insertNode(span);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  select me selet me select me select me. select me selet me select me select me. select me selet me select me select me. select me selet me select me select me. select me selet me select me select me. select me selet me select me select me.
</div>
```

Совместимость смотрите в описании [.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) и [.getRangeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt)

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988468/5398808)

Comment: Этот вариант можно как-то переделать под оборачивание тэгом по нажатию кнопки? А то я выделяю одну букву, и она оборачивается в 8 тэгов span. Хотелось бы, чтобы в один тэг.

Comment: конечно, вместо `$(document).on("mouseup", ".test", function() {
    styliString();
  });` используйте  `$(document).on("click", ".btn-test", function() {
  styliString();
});`

Comment: @ВикторПавлов по выделению в 8 тегов - при одном выделении выделенный текст оборачивается только одним `span`.

Comment: Не работает, наверное потому, что выделение текста пропадает при клике на кнопку.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов работает. см. пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amateur009/gdtfa09s/1/). Выделение текста не может пропадать при простом нажатии на кнопку.