# Получить позиции выделенного текста в div contenteditable

Tags: jquery, select, текст

Второй день парюсь. Решил задать вопрос здесь.

Есть:

```
<div contenteditabled="true" class="editor">text, my text. Get selected text, please help me to get position of selected text</div>
```

На jquery пытаюсь найти позиции (начало и конец) выделенного текста. Перепробовал несколько функций из Гугла, но нормальной не нашел.

Как получить позиции? Нужно для того, чтобы обернуть выделенный текст в тег `<b>...</b>`

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797847/Как-выделенный-текст-обернуть-в-тэг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797847/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%8D%D0%B3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeSelected(){
if (window.getSelection() == '') {
return false;
}
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.appendChild(selectionContents);
span.setAttribute("class", "selected");
span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
span.style.color = "green";
range.insertNode(span);
}
```

Правда, не знаю стоит ли добавить `document.selection`?